# How to revert from using an encrypted home partition?

Tags: 14.04, encryption, home-directory

I tried to delete `ecryptfs` from my computer so I wrote in the terminal

```
$ PRIVATE=`cat ~/.ecryptfs/Private.mnt 2>/dev/null || echo $HOME/Private`
$ ecryptfs-umount-private
```

and now my home folder seems to be empty.

How can I restore my data? I had there important data. Do I need to mount my home folder back? If so, how can I do it? I tried rebooting, which didn't help.

And how do I revert from using an encrypted home folder without losing my data? I don't want to use `ecryptfs` anymore, and all my current data should be available in plain on my hard drive.

**EDIT:** The result for these commands:

```
$ ls /home/.ecryptfs/my_user/.Private | head
ECRYPTFS_FNEK_ENCRYPTED.FWbOl2isOC9ScESAHyXJKgdV6pdWpf-xTJML0HpAyj4B47gvi8NfhNPzQE--
ECRYPTFS_FNEK_ENCRYPTED.FWbOl2isOC9ScESAHyXJKgdV6pdWpf-xTJML1NoC3E4VG6lgU7ry20gLR---
ECRYPTFS_FNEK_ENCRYPTED.FWbOl2isOC9ScESAHyXJKgdV6pdWpf-xTJML2EdR95BqA7AdiKe9d71xA---
ECRYPTFS_FNEK_ENCRYPTED.FWbOl2isOC9ScESAHyXJKgdV6pdWpf-xTJML4kKEf3amHWtlShyHiveiq---
ECRYPTFS_FNEK_ENCRYPTED.FWbOl2isOC9ScESAHyXJKgdV6pdWpf-xTJML4mnnK0ObQGfJgsbnilThfk--
ECRYPTFS_FNEK_ENCRYPTED.FWbOl2isOC9ScESAHyXJKgdV6pdWpf-xTJML-4VDqP7q4LxuMItSFeBdrE--
ECRYPTFS_FNEK_ENCRYPTED.FWbOl2isOC9ScESAHyXJKgdV6pdWpf-xTJML4xJnWwKHLnpPRVRK4yx7UU--
ECRYPTFS_FNEK_ENCRYPTED.FWbOl2isOC9ScESAHyXJKgdV6pdWpf-xTJML6E2-IFSM7hF5gjV26PgpJk--
ECRYPTFS_FNEK_ENCRYPTED.FWbOl2isOC9ScESAHyXJKgdV6pdWpf-xTJML77wgt4UK7NPKBNKpu.BJzE--
ECRYPTFS_FNEK_ENCRYPTED.FWbOl2isOC9ScESAHyXJKgdV6pdWpf-xTJML8a2bimSR65c9rtSsoDQWlU--

$ ls /home/.ecryptfs/my_user/.ecryptfs
auto-mount  auto-umount  Private.mnt  Private.sig  wrapped-passphrase

$ cat /home/.ecryptfs/my_user/.ecryptfs/Private.mnt
/home/my_user
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can recover your encrypted data by issuing the following command:

```
sudo ecryptfs-recover-private
```

You will see an output such as this:

```
INFO: Searching for encrypted private directories (this might take a while)...
INFO: Found [/home/.ecryptfs/USERNAME/.Private].
Try to recover this directory? [Y/n]:
```

Hit enter, and follow the steps...

```
INFO: Found your wrapped-passphrase
Do you know your LOGIN passphrase? [Y/n] Y
INFO: Enter your LOGIN passphrase...
Inserted auth tok with sig [xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx] into the user session keyring
INFO: Success! Private data mounted at [/tmp/ecryptfs.m6OUhFlJ]
```

You can now access all your data in the folder `/tmp/ecryptfs.m6OUhFlJ` (or similar, the text after the dot is random). You will need to copy all of that where you want it (e.g., in your home folder), using a file browser or by using something like:

```
rsync -Cav /tmp/ecryptfs.m6OUhFlJ/ ~
```

Note that you will need *at least as much free space as the size of the encrypted data for this*. Otherwise you will have to use an external hard disk or some such to copy your unencrypted data to.

Finally, you can remove the `ecryptfs` utilities using either the Software Center or a command such as

```
sudo apt-get remove ecryptfs-utils
```

...and now, to free space, **and only once you've made sure that all your unencrypted data has been copied somewhere safe**,  you can remove the encrypted data. **Careful! This will irrevocably delete ALL your encrypted data! Use with caution!**

```
sudo rm -r /home/.ecryptfs/USERNAME
```

Comment: Thanks again for everything :) p.s: Can you remove from the answer the string indicates my login-password (Don't want people to find it out)?

Comment: You're welcome. And sorry, I didn't realize. Done. :)